# h:selectBooleanCheckbox valueChangeListener is not working

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I am facing trouble with the `valueChangeListener` of `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`. I have the following code block:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <link href="../css/profile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/twt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/custom-form-elements.js"></script>
    <a4j:form id="userList">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="userListPanel" rendered="#{popupController.iIndex >= 0}">          
            <div id="listPopup_#{popupController.iIndex}" 
                style="width: 202px; height: 235px; position: absolute; right: 0%; display: none; z-index: 10000; 
                background-image: url('../images/Alert/createNewListBack.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                <table width="180" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 10px;">
                    <a4j:repeat id="userListRepeat" value="#{popupController.userList}" rowKeyVar="i" var="listByUser">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" align="center" width="35" style="padding-left: 8px;">                               
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="listCheckbox_#{i}" name="listCheckbox_#{i}"                                                                        
                                valueChangeListener="#{popupController.addUserListMember}" immediate="true">

                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle" align="left" class="alertSelect" width="145">
                                <div style="width: 170px; height: auto; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
                                    <h:outputText style="padding-right: 8px;" value="#{listByUser.name}" />                                 
                                </div>                              
                            </td>
                        </tr>                                           
                    </a4j:repeat>                   
                </table>    
            </div>          
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </a4j:form>

</ui:composition>
```

And the addUserListMember of PopupController is

```
public void addUserListMember(ValueChangeEvent event) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("=========================== PopupController.addUserListMember() ==================");
    Boolean isChecked = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
    if(isChecked) {
        System.out.println("===== Checked =====");                                              
    } else {
        System.out.println("===== Un Checked =====");
    }                
}
```

But the `valuechangelistner` is not working. I can't use `this.form.submit()` because it will not fit into the code. I am in jsf 1.2.

What is the remedy? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` is not a client side event/happening. It's fully server side. You should really submit the form to the server side after you change the value in order to get it invoked.

As you're apparently already using Ajax4jsf, you could just add an [`<a4j:support>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html).

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox ...>
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="someOtherComponentIfNecessary" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to use it like: `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox valueChangeListener="#{popupController.addUserListMember}"> <a4j:support event="onclick"/></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`

Comment: Perhaps your `popupController` bean is request scoped and the datamodel for `<a4j:repeat>` is not properly been preserved in bean's constructor. Try adding `<a4j:keepAlive beanName="popupController" />` to the view, somewhere after the `</a4j:form>`.

Comment: Well, that'll be RichFaces/Ajax4jsf specific then. I don't know as I'm not fully familiar with it RF 3.x. I'll delete the answer soon. A similar RF 4.x / JSF 2.x targeted construct would have worked just fine.

Comment: Is it a Bug? I mean I found various websites and forums where many problems related to `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` and `valueChangeListener` wre discussed. That why I am asking it.

Comment: The problem is solved. The `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` is within a repeater whose value previously taken from a controller which is in the request scope and that's why the `actionlistener` was not firing even `a4j:commandLink` is used. I changed it to the another controller which is in session scope. And the action is firing up. But the `valueChangeListener` with `<a4j:support event="onclick">` firing same method three times. Can you help me?

Comment: There are apparently 3 items repeated by the repeater and apparently all the three items are been submitted to the server when one of them is changed.

Comment: yes you are right. there are three items. So what is the remedy?

Comment: Perhaps you've a `onclick="this.form.submit()"` which is overriding the `<a4j:support>`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is nothing like form.submit(). `<a4j:repeat id="userListRepeat" value="#{rtopHandler.userList}" rowKeyVar="i" var="listByUser">
      <tr>
       <td valign="middle" align="center" width="35" style="padding-left: 8px;">                
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{popupController.addUserListMember}">
         <a4j:support event="onchange" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>       
       </td>
       
      </tr>           
     </a4j:repeat> `

Comment: I am not highly famliar with RichFaces 3.x (only 4.x which is has a quite different ajax approach). Try a normal `<h:form>` instead of `<a4j:form>`. Perhaps the `<a4j:form>` implies that all of the input elements has to be submitted.